# Arrange excel columns based on first column

Tags: excel

Basically I have 2 columns of data in excel, A and B. Does anyone know how to arrange column A in descending order but also have the associated information in column B follow the data in column A.

Secondly, say I have two pieces of data in column A that have the same value, how can I order the information in descending order based on the values in column B in that case?

Comment: Select both columns.  Click data tab, click sort button, Apply sort logic desired.

Comment: To piggy back on xQbert, the sort logic you want is "Column A Largest to Smallest" Then "Column B Largest to Smallest". You'll see what we're talking about after you hit the "Sort" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this??
[image]